Convolution of line segment and bell-shaped function
I'm trying to calculate a convolution integral of two functions:

A bell-shaped function:

$$
f(x,n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}  \sqrt{\pi} \cos ^n(\pi  x) & -\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

A line segment that intersects two points $(x1,y1)$ and $(x2,y2)$ whose width is $x2-x1$:

$$g(x,x1,y1,x2,y2)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{(x-\text{x1}) (\text{y2}-\text{y1})}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}}+\text{y1} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{x}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
Here $\sqrt{\pi}$ and gammas makes sure that the integral of $f$ is always equal to one for all valid values of $n$.
Here's an example plot of $f(x,-1,3,1,5)$ and $f(x,4)$:

However my calculus skills are somewhat rusty and the result of my calculation yields zero every time so I need help in pointing out where I made the mistake.
According to definition of convolution:
$$(f * g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau, n) g(t - \tau, x1, y1, x2, y2) \, d\tau$$
would look like this:
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(
\begin{cases}
\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}  \sqrt{\pi} \cos ^n(\pi \tau) & -\frac{1}{2} < \tau < \frac{1}{2}
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 \cdot
\begin{cases}
 \frac{(t-\text{x1}-\tau ) (\text{y2}-\text{y1})}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}}+\text{y1} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t-\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\right) \, d\tau$$
Which is a good candidate for integration by parts. To make matters more simple for performing integration by parts I have calculated an integral of $f(x,n)$ for all natural $n$ which is equal to:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} x -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \sin (\pi  x) \cos ^m(\pi  x)}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)} & -\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Now to integrate by parts we have:
$$\int u \, dv=u v-\int v \, du$$
where:
$$u=
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{y1}+\frac{(\text{y2}-\text{y1}) (t-\text{x1}-\tau )}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t-\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}$$
$$\text{dv}=\left(
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\cos ^n(\pi  x) \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} & -\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{d\tau }{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}\right)d\tau
$$
$$v=
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \tau -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau ) \sin (\pi  \tau )}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}<\tau <\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{sgn}(\tau )}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}$$
$$
du=\left(
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t}{x2-x1}-\frac{\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
\right)d\tau
$$
Which allows to rewrite original convolution integral as:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{y1}+\frac{(\text{y2}-\text{y1}) (t-\text{x1}-\tau )}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t-\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
\cdot
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \tau -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau ) \sin (\pi  \tau )}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}<\tau <\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{sgn}(\tau )}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}\\
-\int
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t}{x2-x1}-\frac{\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
\cdot
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \tau -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau ) \sin (\pi  \tau )}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}<\tau <\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{sgn}(\tau )}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
\, d\tau$$
Let's focus on indefinite integral and simplify multiplication of two piecewise functions:
$$\int
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}} & \tau \geq \frac{1}{2}\land t-\frac{x2-x1}{2}<\tau <t+\frac{x2-x1}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2}\leq \tau \lor \tau \leq -\frac{1}{2}\lor \tau \leq t-\frac{x2-x1}{2}\lor t+\frac{x2-x1}{2}\leq \tau  \\
 \frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}}
\left(
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} \tau -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \sin (\pi  \tau) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau)}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}
\right) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
 \, d\tau$$
It's now easy to apply integral to all piecewise cases and by remembering that:
$$\int \sin (\pi  \tau ) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau ) \, d\tau =\frac{\cos ^{m+1}(\pi  \tau )}{\pi  (m+1)}$$
we get final shape of the indefinite integral:
$$\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{y1}+\frac{(\text{y2}-\text{y1}) (t-\text{x1}-\tau )}{\text{x2}-\text{x1}} & -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t-\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
\cdot
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \tau -\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \cos ^m(\pi  \tau ) \sin (\pi  \tau )}{4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}<\tau <\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{sgn}(\tau )}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}-
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{(\text{y2}-\text{y1}) \tau }{\text{x1}-\text{x2}} & \tau \geq \frac{1}{2}\land -\frac{1}{2}<\frac{t}{x2-x1}-\frac{\tau }{x2-x1}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \tau \geq \frac{1}{2}\lor \tau \leq -\frac{1}{2}\lor \frac{t}{x2-x1}-\frac{\tau }{x2-x1}\geq \frac{1}{2}\lor \frac{t}{x2-x1}-\frac{\tau }{x2-x1}\leq -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{\text{x1}-\text{x2}}\left(\frac{1}{4} (-1)^n \tau ^2+\frac{\tau ^2}{4}+\frac{\tau }{2}-\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left(\left((-1)^{m+n}-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\right) \cos ^{m+1}(\pi  \tau )}{\left(4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)\right) ((m+1) \pi )}\right) & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Now the problem I'm facing is related to applying integral range values, however when I substitute $\tau$ with $-\infty$ or $+\infty$. I get zero just based on definition of piecewise function. I'm pretty sure that the calculation is correct but I can't wrap my head around why the result is wrong

Suggestion. The easiest way to compute such tedious convolutions is to first learn about the  properties of the Laplace transform operator $L$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform, because  of the identity $L(fg)=L(f) L(g)$. Then use a  computer algebra system to find the inverse Laplace transform of the right-hand side to solve for $fg$ itself.  P.S. By convention, the Laplace transform assumes all functions are zero unless $x>0$. Thus you will need to slide all your functions rightward to satisfy this convention. At the end, slide back the equal but opposite amount.

I tried using Laplace transforms and discovered that Mathematica chokes. Thus I decided to try working out the answer by brute force hand calculation. Here are some suggestions that should help. Good luck with the final messy details.

Aside from annoying constants, we have  $f(x)=I(x) \cos^n (\pi  x)$ where $I(x)$ is the  indicator function of the interval $(-1/2,1/2)$.

The next simplifying trick is to shift all the functions rightward by 1 unit and then change the scale of the variable of integration by a factor of $\pi$ so that now
(i) $I(x)$ is the indicator function of the interval $[0, \pi]$
(ii) $f(x) = \sin^n (x) I(x),$
(iii) $ g(x)= (mx+b) I(x)$.

Note that  e.g. $2\cos(x)= e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}$.  You can raise this to the $n_{th}$ power to express $2^n \cos^n(x)$  in powers of $e^{ix}$ whose coefficients are various binomial coefficients.
Similarly for the sine function powers.

Thus you will end up wishing to integrate  expressions of the form $\int  (b+ m(x-t)e^{ik t} I(x-t) I(t) dt$
The limits of integration
Note that for any assigned value of the parameter $x$, the expression $I(x-t) I(t)$ (regarded as a function of the integration variable $t$) is the indicator function of some new $t$-interval whose endpoints depend on $x$. Once you determine the details of what those two endpoints are, (draw a picture!) you can  integrate (5) over that interval.
In fact $I(x-t) I(t)$ is nonzero iff $0<x-t<\pi, 0<t<\pi$.
Plotting the solutions of these inequalities in the $(x,t)$ plane allows you to work out the limits of integration for $t$. There will be several cases that depend on the values of $x$.
Case 1. If $0<x<\pi$ then the interval of integration is $t\in[0,x]$
Case 2. If $\pi<x<2\pi$ then the interval of integration is $t\in [x-\pi, \pi]$
In all other cases the interval of integration is the empty set.
The picture below sketches these inequalities in the $(t,x)$ plane. It illustrates with red lines the two cases discussed above. (Unfortunately the axis  unit values labeled as 1 need to be multiplied by $\pi$.)

Additional integration identities
Eventually you express the answer as a  linear combination of  values of these general indefinite integrals $A(u)=\int e^{i k u} du$ and $B(u) =\int  u e^{i k u} du$ ( of course evaluated at various limits of integration that depend on $x$).
You can exploit the  sneaky identity $\frac{d}{dk} A(u)= i B(u)$
to quickly get a closed-form description of the more troublesome indefinite integral $B$ in terms of the easier expression $A$. (Note that we are differentiating in $k$ rather than in $u$!)
Thus the key indefinite integrals you will need turn out to be  $A= \frac{e^{i ku}}{k}$ and $iB =\frac{d}{dk}\frac{e^{i ku}}{k}=iu \frac{e^{i ku}}{k} -\frac{e^{i ku}}{k^2}$
As a check on your calculations here is one example of what I got using Mathematica:
$\int t \sin^6 t dt =\frac{5 t^2}{32}-\frac{15}{64} t \sin (2 t)+\frac{3}{64} t \sin (4 t)-\frac{1}{192} t
   \sin (6 t)-\frac{15}{128} \cos (2 t)+\frac{3}{256} \cos (4 t)-\frac{\cos (6 t)}{1152}$

Thank you MathFont for your answer, interesting idea regarding solving for derivative will try it. Tbh this is a multi-year journey on my end and I've exhausted most CAS options Mathematica/Maple/SymPy. No CAS will evaluate this convolution directly and even with tricks it would yield extremely large ten-floor Piecewise functions filled with Hypergemetric functions making the solution impractical. I'm familiar with LaplaceTransform but the issue is the same either inability to perform calculation directly or the result is overly complicated. Thank you for your suggestions though!

See updated list of suggestions.. Good luck!

Yes, thank you! I'm still trying previous set of suggestions, I'm performing large part of calculations manually

By the way taking the route with derivatives produces recurrent solutions that just reduces the power of $n$ in cosine by one and the integral with $n-1$ power remains. I'm trying to figure out this indicator function if I understand correctly it's equivalent to Mathematica's UnitBox which might prevent the use of Piecewise functions? If so than I've ended up with using Piecewise functions one step earlier prior to the moment I've figured out the that it's possible to use integration by parts. Might need to make a step back because the final solution is still 5mb in size with piecewise fns.

And by the way yes, $n$-th power of cosine does yield various binomial coefficients which by the way trigger various undecidable edge cases when it's arguments are nearing zero. The most general approach is the one that would use hypergeometric functions yet again in reality there is little point in having non-integer or negative values of $n$. Also interesting how hypergeometric functions for non-integer $n$ are close to linear combination of the same function for $n-1$, $n$ or $n$, $n+1$. In most cases the difference is so subtle that machine precision is not enough to represent difference.

I think everything can be evaluated without using hypergeometric functions, but it is very messy.

No, no, the indicator function approach seems to be working fine with integration by parts (which has to be applied twice though). I've used to slightly different terminology to indicator function though, on my end it is either UnitBox or HeavisidePi functions, actually HeavisidePi is the one that works properly with differentiation here as UnitBox needs to be used twice and at intersection introduces a discontinuity at 1/2, -1/2 where function suddenly jumps to 2 rather than 1 at 1/2 and -1/2. Feels like I'm really close to solution. Thanks again!
